# infinite loop when compiling vim from source code

Tags: installing

I use two servers, both using redhat, and I need to most of work on server, not on my PC. My sysadmin did not update vim for a very long time, like, system's default vim version is 6.x, which is really horrible. Since I cannot get sudo privilege, I thought it would be good to compile vim myself from its source just for myself.

I followed instructions posted [HERE](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source), but I only used `enable-pythoninterp`, `prefix`, and `with-python-config-dir` options for configure.
After I compiled vim (version 7.4.691) for the first machine, I moved on to the second one, with the same source code. I did the same `./configure` and `make`, but it took forever (about an hour before I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) so I am really confused right now.

I checked the output, and I found out that everything is being repeated with following message,

```
config.status: creating auto/config.h
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 2.4e+09 s in the future
```

Why this behaviour, and how to solve this problem?

Comment: You may want to try to compile with the clean source code rather than using compiled source tree from first machine. Or perhaps you can check suggested answer for similar error message here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281050/makefile-warning-warning-file-main-cpp-has-modification-time-2-1e04-s-in-th

Comment: If you can move the source compilation to a local disk (one not on a network drive). Run make clean and reconfigure the project (you might need to touch all the files in the tree to set the modification time to now.) Then recompile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I solved problem by myself, and I wanted to share what I found.

I downloaded the most recent version from [Google](https://code.google.com/p/vim/) as a `zip` format, and I uploaded to my server, unzip, and tried to compile.

The thing is, files inside .zip did not have any `Timestamp`. While extracting, arbitrary timestamps were inserted. In my first server, all missing timestamps are filled with some arbitrary number, either too large or too small. Some files were stamped as year 1953, while some critical files, such as `configure` had year 2092-08-05.

Makefile compared timestamps and got error. This caused infinitely looping `make` procedure.

Solution? I just `scp`ed all *extracted* source codes from my 1st server, since it had no problem installing it. As I thought, those source codes had consistent timestamps. (By consistent, I mean, *after unix epoch*. They all had like 1979.)

So, it is highly unlikely anybody experiencing the same problem, but if so, you should check the timestamps.

Comment: Is this the same problem as [issue 208](https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/detail?id=208)? Please report there how to solve it, so we can perhaps change it later.

Comment: I think that is the same problem with this. I posted a comment there. Thank you for noting me.

Comment: You can set the mtime of a file with the `touch` command. For example: `touch Makefile`. You combine this with `find` to run this on a large number of files: `find /path/to/vim/sources -exec touch {} +`